# Are there events for those 2 actions?

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, ce-1.8.0.0

1) When user submits an "Email to Friend" form.

2) When user submits his email for Newsletter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And awesome-but-non-obvious events strike again!

Both of your use cases involve user requests. There are always two unique events for actions. The sequence of method calls in a typical dispatch is as follows:

- [`Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::dispatch()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L398)

  - [::preDispatch()](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L469)
  - [(the action)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L418)
  - [::postDispatch()](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php#L418)

The automagic events are called in this action controller superclass in the `preDispatch()` and `postDispatch()` methods:

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    //snip...
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_action_predispatch_' . $this->getFullActionName(),
        array('controller_action' => $this));
}
```

and

```
public function postDispatch()
{
    //snip...
    Mage::dispatchEvent(
        'controller_action_postdispatch_'.$this->getFullActionName(),
        array('controller_action'=>$this)
    );
    //snip...
}
```

In the case of the email to a friend action, you want to capture the input from the user, which is `POST`ed to the `Mage_Sendfriend_ProductController::sendmailAction()`. Even though there is a redirect set on success (or on error), you can still capture the POST request by observing `controller_action_postdispatch_sendfriend_product_sendmail`. Of course, there's not a really graceful way of capturing whether the transaction was a success or a failure (checking session message storage for success or error is the only obvious way), but this should get you started.

The newsletter post is a similar case - that form action is pointed to `Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController::newAction()`, so you can observe `controller_action_postdispatch_newsletter_subscriber_new`. However, this action involves a model with some business logic (see [`Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::subscribe()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php#L307), and when the instance is saved, it will dispatch automagic events of its own as part of Magento's ORM event hooks (namely `newsletter_subscriber_save_before` and `newsletter_subscriber_save_after`).

So, like my friend [Vinai](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/766/vinai) says, Magento is "all about options," including when it comes to hooking into newsletter subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

Well I searched for `Mage::dispatchEvent('` in magento folder using my editor and found:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('sendfriend_product', array('product' => $product));
```

But I did not found anything for Newsletter.